# how to store a php directory structure and transfer it to javascript?

Tags: php, directory

how to store a php directory structure and transfer it to javascript?

I've got the code for recursively checking if its a file or folder , and also for json coding for displaying the structure.but the middle part of storing the php structure and transferring as json is missing

Answer (score 2):

Show us your function/code for recursive directory listing and we will try to help. But in general - you will be pushing items into array and then you encode it into json string.
For json encoding use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: <?php
function recursivefolderscan()
{
$var_path = path;
$var_list=scandir($var_path);

foreach($var_list as $val)
{
 if(is_dir($val))
 {
  }
 
 else
 {
  }
}
}

?>